# Can't set calendar reminder in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, google-calendar, lightning

I am using the Provider for Google Calendar add on to add my Google calendars into the Lightning calendar add on for Thunderbird. I am able to setup reminders for calendar events that I create, but if someone invites me to an event I am not able to add a reminder. Does anybody know how to do this? I can add the reminder on the web version of Google calendar, but that setting doesn't sync to Thunderbird.

Answer (score 4):

That appears to be a bug in Thunderbird: [799505 -No reminders for events organized by someone else](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=799505)

There is a related bug report / feature request open since August 2008: [451380 -Events from accepted invitations cannot be edited or updated locally](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451380)